# Page is not Staying Constant when you Zoom in or Out in Firefox

Tags: css

Click on http://www.christopherandbanks.com/home/index.jsp and when you Zoom-in or zoom out  Firefox the Shopping bag Disappears.
You can Use firebug for the Help.
This is only a CSS Related Issue.

Comment: Please Help..Shopping bag movies at the bottom, you can see it by removing the over-flow hidden property.

Comment: No one is helping because no one see the bag. I just saw it but it was difficult to find. (Maybe because of the width of my screen)

Comment: Its Crystal Clear on the top-right. :-)

Comment: in Shopping Bag [Items] the "ems]" things pop's out after you Zoom-in in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your div which holds the shopping cart and other links besides it, add `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: You will have to add to div#utilNavTop

Comment: I did but still It Pop's Out. :-(

Comment: Add width:0 and white-space:nowrap to your list item with class .last. It will work.

Comment: But still Items Pop's Out .. any solution for it?

Comment: Which items now pop out?

Comment: in Shopping Bag [Items] the "ems]" things pop's out after you Zoom-in in Firefox.

Comment: in Shopping Bag [Items] the "ems]" things pop's out after you Zoom-in in Firefox